# Discord бот который играет музыку 24/7 в голосовом канале

Tags: python, discord, бот

Всем здравствуйте.

Бот который 24/7 воспроизводит музыку в голосовом канале. Но при переходе к следующему плейлисту возникает ошибка Not connected to voice, хотя бот подключён к голосовому каналу

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Kirill\Python\lib\site-packages\disnake\ui\view.py", line 385, in
_scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)   File "c:\Kirill\Projects\DIRECTORY\music.py", line 64, in callback
    await play_playlist(inter, inter.values[0])   File "c:\Kirill\Projects\DIRECTORY\music.py", line 152, in play_playlist
    vc.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))   File "C:\Kirill\Python\lib\site-packages\disnake\voice_client.py", line 572, in play
    raise ClientException("Not connected to voice.") disnake.errors.ClientException: Not connected to voice.
```

ЦИКЛ:

````
 ```is_play = True
while is_play:
  for j in range(int(i), len(playlist)):
    if is_play == False:
      break
    await inter.edit_original_message(‘**Get playlist info**\n*Wait for it*’, view=None)
    try:
      with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
        info = ydl.extract_info(playlist[j][1], download=False)
    except:
      await inter.edit_original_message('Cannot download it')
      break
    for m in range(len(info['entries'])):
      if is_play == False or next_playlist == True:
        next_playlist = False
        break
      name = info['entries'][m]['title']
      n = len(info['entries'])
      await inter.edit_original_message(f’Playlist **{j+1}/{len(playlist)}**:\n```\n{playlist[j][0]}\n```\nVideo **{m+1}/{n}**:\n```\n{name}\```’, view=None)
      url = info['entries'][m]['formats'][0]['url']
      vc.play(disnake.FFmpegPCMAudio(url, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
      while vc.is_playing():
        await sleep(1)
  i = 0
vc = None ```
````

Comment: дай вопросу заголовок, отражающий твою проблему, а не не набор тэгов

Comment: Как происходит подключение к голосовому каналу?

Comment: @JackOwest v_channel = inter.author.voice.channel
vc = await v_channel.connect(reconnect=True)